# Optimization of Integral over Decreasing Functions with Varying Integration Limit

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

I need to minimize the following
$$ \int_0^{T(b)} \left(e^{-x \: t}a \cdot b(t) - e^{-y\:t} c \right)\: dt $$ 
over the space of weakly decreasing functions (so I have the constraint that $\dot{b}(t)\leq 0$), where the upper integration limit $T(b)$ is given by the solution to
$$ \int_0^{T(b)}\left( e^{-x \: t} f \cdot b(t) - e^{-y \: t} g \: c\right) \:dt = V.$$
I did not know whether there is an extension of the standard calculus of variation approach for varying integration limits.

Comment: What exactly is $b$ here? It shows up as the argument to the function $T$, but then it's also inside the integrand as the function $b(t)$. Nice question, by the way. +1.

Comment: $b$ just means to indicate that $T$ depends on the entire function $b(t)$ as it has to be chosen such that it satisfies the constraint; so $T( (b(t)_{t\geq 0})$. Suppose that $b(t)$ were constant, then $T$ has to be sufficiently large such that the second integral equals $V$. And analogous for other $b(t)$. Thanks for the clarifying question.